# Install VPN client issue

Tags: vpn, windows-vista

I'm trying to install the Shrew VPN client. In the process of installation an error occurs:

> Error 0x800f0203: Couldn't install the network component.

It occurs when the installer tries to execute

> C:\Program Files\ShrewSoft\VPN Client\netcfg.exe -add service vflt C:\Program Files\ShrewSoft\VPN Client\drivers\vfilter.inf

Antivirus, firewall, etc are disabled and I'm running as an administrator.

I've installed vfilter.inf manually, but it leads nowhere.

I have a similar situation with the Cisco VPN client. I need a VPN client supports group authorization, and imports the settings from pcf format.

---

Windows Vista 32-bit, Shrew client 2.1.5, also try 2.0.0 for 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

It may be as a result of a corrupt file called `infcache.1` in the `%windir%\Inf` directory. As the name implies, `infcache.1` is a file that caches driver inf files. Find that file and rename it to `infcache.1.bak`

You should be able to install the Shrew VPN client after that. I would recommend first uninstalling all VPN clients that you've already tried to install and then rebooting. Rename the infcache.1 file first thing after a reboot. You may have to reboot again before trying the installation.